# how to launch app from USB with no admin rights

Tags: windows, usb, administration

I want to know if there is any way to launch applications (portable ones) from a USB device, I have to mention that I am a normal user, and the box's administrator has blocked launching apps from a USB.

Comment: You mean launch the app automatically when the drive is plugged into the PC?

Comment: Why do you need to do this? I hate to be picky, but it doesn't seem like there are a ton of legitmate uses for this, especially since the administrator has blocked it.  I could be wrong, though...

Comment: ok ..it's against the rule in my enterprise....but I really need this trick...

Comment: Make sure your résumé is up to date.

Answer (score 1):

If your administrator blocked launching apps from a USB drive, then good for him/her. I have dealt with viruses that are spread via removable drive and they wasted a lot of time and money to fix. Even if you could get around your administrator's security restrictions, **don't.** Just copy your app to a local disk and run it that way.

Remember, your administrator is there to help avoid problems. When you try to work around the administrator, you will likely introduce problems.

Comment: ok ..it's against the rule in my enterprise....but I really need this trick...

Comment: Right now it sounds like what you're doing is malicious. Malicious people should not have this kind of info.

Answer (score 0):

I think many usb/CD's have an Autorun.inf file, from where they can do some commands.
Example of one from my usb

```
[autorun] 
 label=MyUSB
 icon=autorun.ico
```

I think there is a command "open = application name here.exe", which can launch applications, that are on the USB, but I'm not sure if you have to have admin rights.
It also depends on XP and win7 users.

I hope this helped :)